# Cucumber testing that I can edit associated record from a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, associations

I have two models: **User** and **Car** with the following associations:

```
User has_many Car
Car belongs to User
```

I am creating a feature for editing cars and here is what I have so far:

```
Feature: Edit car for a user 
  In order to edit cars of my user
  As a user
  I should be able to edit existing users related to my account

Scenario: User is signed in and edits an education with valid attributes 
  Given I am logged in as a user
  And I have the following cars related to my account
  Then I want to edit a car...
```

The only step I have implemented is this one:

```
Given /^I am logged in as a user$/ do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  user_sign_in
end


def user_sign_in
 visit '/users/sign_in'
 fill_in "Email", :with => @user[:email]
 fill_in "Password", :with => @user[:password]
 click_button "Go"
end
```

I am basically failing to see how would I create cars associated to this user and how would I test that I am able to edit one of those cars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The then should only be output testing as to Cucumber's wiki. You should tansform it to a when.

I am new to cucumber, but I think you should do something like this (cucumber likes precise examples):

```
Given I am logged in
And I have "Ferrari" related to my account
When I edit "Ferrari"
Then "Ferrari" should be modified.
```

Or any other car type.

In your given, you set up your variables. Since your are not testing the authentication functionnality of your website, you can simply log the user in with your User class method. It will speed up your test. The steps should look like this :

Given I am logged in -> login the user

And I have... -> @car = Car.create!(your params)

When... -> this should modify @car

```
visit car_edit_path(your car id)
Fill....
Sumbmit
```

Then -> verify that @car was modified

In the when, you use your model method to modify the car and in the then, you verify if the car as been changed or not.

Comment: How do I test that the car is related to a specific user (the one who is logged in).?

Comment: Before you created the car in the given/and, no cars named Ferrari was relate to your user account. Now, to test that it was created, you do the following ruby (to be tested) : `user.cars.map(&:name).include? "Ferrari"`